# Changing Metadata of an Epub in iBooks

Tags: books

How can I edit the metadata of an Epub file? I would like to alter the title, author, and cover art, similar to how I was able to do so in iTunes (get info).

Answer (score 7):

Just started using iBooks on Mac tonight. I was worried about the same thing.

Here's what works:

- Go to **List view** in iBooks »
- Click once on a book (anywhere on the line) »
- Wait a couple of seconds »
- Click once on the data that you want to change or enter »
- That entry will become editable

You can edit anything: **Title**, **Author**, **Category**, etc. Voilà!

Comment: What version of iBooks are you using? This does not work for me with Mavericks.

Comment: Great, thanks! Pheew, I was starting to look for a third party metadata editor. No needs then.

Comment: Actually, you can edit the following fields:
* Title
* Author
* Category
* Description
* Year
* Comments

Don't understand why, but, we cannot edit:
* Kind
* Release date
* Series
* Issue Number
* Version number

Also, sometimes, "Page count" displays nothing and is not editable either… Weird. Means, iBooks is not capable to extract this info from the book at listing time? Huh.

Anyway, still good enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

The current version 1.0.1 of iBooks stores your PDF and epub files in the folder ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books so you should be able to edit the files with the usual suspects.

Additionally, you might still be able add files to iTunes, make the changes you wish and then use iBooks -> File -> Move Books from iTunes to bring your modified titles into the iBooks storage sandbox.

Comment: What are "the usual suspects"?

Comment: The default app for the document you use to manage your library, which can change name based on macOS version. In 2013 those were iBooks and previously iTunes which are named here @Glyph

Answer (score 1):

You can use a piece of software called Calibre to edit the metadata of an epub and then reimport it to iBooks, as long as it was not purchased at a store that uses DRM.